# How to label a migration as included on a newly-created DB

Tags: entity-framework

I have a team developing a web application using EF. They all have local copies of their DB, as well as there being a central DB for a published version of the app. Some of the devs, and the CI server, have built their initial DB from a later version of the model than others, and so when they run Update-Database or the migrate.exe tool, they get errors when running migrations they don't actually need.

Other than blowing away all DBs and starting over, what's the best way to get everyone on the same page migrations-wise? Can migrate or Update-Database be told to mark migrations as being applied even if they fail, and continue?